# GeoServer/Geoexplorer: How do I hide the WMSLegend on some layers?

Tags: geoserver, geoexplorer

I'm developing with the geoexplorer sdk and extending the composer and am working on the master branch of boundless/suite/geoexplorer. My geoserver version is 2.4-SNAPSHOT.

I want to hide the wmslegend image for some layers.

My immediate thought is to edit the way that the nodes are added into the layer tree groups so that they are collapsable.  Is this something I need to change when the tree panel is instantiated or in the object prototype itself?

As a short run workaround, is there a configuration setting on geoserver that I can change to turn off legend image service?

Comment: I only want to turn off the legend service on a layer by layer level, not globally.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, what I did was create more layer tree groups in LayerTree.js . This made it possible to hide and show certain layers.